# How to convert Unix epoch time in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, unix, epoch

Could you help me convert UNIX epoch time into format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (24h) in SQLite? (GMT+7 would be appreciated).

Example: from `1319017136629` to `Wednesday, October 19, 2011 4:38:56 PM GMT+7`.

p/s: Just looked around and found a solution:

```
SELECT datetime(1319017136629, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

But i am still looking for a way to batch convert UNIX epoch time in SQLite.

Comment: Store in the database in UTC, display to the user in their local time. To do anything else is just *asking* for trouble

Comment: @Petesh how is Epoch timestamp aka Unix time "asking for trouble"?

Answer (score 43):

`1319017136629` is a value in `milliseconds`, which is not `UNIX` epoch time;
therefore it has to be divided by `1000` and rounded to integer `seconds`; only then `DATE()` and `DATETIME()` will convert.

```
SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(dateColumn / 1000), 'unixepoch') AS isodate FROM tableName
```

Converting database values to `localtime` is unfortunate; conversion on output is less problematic.

The [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) might already be worth a consideration.

Answer (score 37):

To change the values in the database, use the `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = datetime(MyColumn, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

Comment: Problem solved. I had to convert sqlite db to mysql. In mysql i have more advanced query:
`UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = from_unixtime(yourcolumn)`

Comment: Remember to NOT directly convert `INT` (for unix timestamps) to `DATETIME`, you have to first change it to `VARCHAR`, convert it with above `UPDATE` statement and then convert it to `DATETIME`. Alternative is to add another column of `DATETIME`, convert old -> new column directly, delete old column and rename new back to old column.

Answer (score 6):

Same as stated above:

`SELECT DATE(ROUND(1601272453000 / 1000), 'unixepoch')`

Comment: Can you explain?